# MySQL - Where does constraint rule is stored in data dictionary?

Tags: mysql

I know I can use `show create table` command to get the constraint rule, for example `CONSTRAINT id_check CHECK ((ID between 1 and 10))`

```
mysql> show create table TESTE7;
+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table  | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                |
+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| TESTE7 | CREATE TABLE `TESTE7` (
  `ID` int DEFAULT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `id_check` CHECK ((`ID` between 1 and 10))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But is there any table which hold this information? `information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` only tell the constraint name and constraint type, It does not specify `((ID between 1 and 10))`

Comment: Why do you ask?

Comment: as an aside, `show create table TESTE7 \G` produces more readable output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see them in

`information_schema`.`CHECK_CONSTRAINTS` table, in `check_clause` column